# Bad practice to return from method before async operation completes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have an Web API 2 end point where by I want to asynchronously carry out an operation while I retrieve and verify a user. If this user does not exist I want to return a 404 Not Found like so:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var getCatTask = GetCatAsync();
    var user = await GetUserAsync();

    if(user == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }     

    var cat = await getCatTask;

    return Ok(cat);
}
```

Could this cause me potential issues if the user was to equal to null and the method returned without awaiting the getCatTask or is it considered a bad practice?

Comment: I guess for performance reasons you could start getting data while you verify the user (I don't think I would do it personally as it brings potential security risks if you accidentally start sending data to the user before its done verifying, but if your carefully and the extra performance really is a must then maybe). However if you return 'not found' it would be nice to abort the async task (as it is wasting processor time). Also since the data can't be personalized (the user is not verified), wouldn't it be nicer to have the 'GetCat' cached somewhere instead of loading it every time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not really *bad*, since in this case you're only reading data and you're just going to ignore the result. You would incur the cost of an extra `GetCatAsync` operation for every fake request (which probably won't happen that often).

If possible, consider making `GetCatAsync` cancelable, and then you'll be able to at least start cleaning up before returning:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
  var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var getCatTask = GetCatAsync(cts.Token);
  var user = await GetUserAsync();

  if (user == null)
  {
    cts.Cancel();
    return NotFound();
  }     

  var cat = await getCatTask;
  return Ok(cat);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is perfectly acceptable. In terms of `async` and `await`, you're not doing anything incorrect. A few notes about the keywords:

The `async` keyword simply enabled the usage of the `await` keyword. The `await` keyword is where all the "magic" happens, i.e.; the async state machine will suspend the method execution and return to that point when the "awaited" asynchronous operation has completed.

One important consideration:

Does the `GetCatAsync()` return a `Task` or `Task<T>` that represents an asynchronous operation that has already started? If so that might be a little problematic, if not you're fine then as it is awaited later. I would suggest adding cancellation though.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var getCatTask = GetCatAsync(cts.Token);
    var user = await GetUserAsync();

    if (user == null)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        return NotFound();
    }     

    var cat = await getCatTask;
    return Ok(cat);
}
```

But, Stephen Cleary beat me to it -- called out above.